# When are the chirp signals orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, special-functions, gm.general-mathematics, signal-analysis

Assume that we have two bounded-time chirp signals,
\begin{align}
x(t)&=\exp\Big(j\pi(\alpha t^2+\beta t+\gamma)\Big),\quad 0\leq t\leq T,\\
y(t)&=\exp\Big(j\pi(\alpha' t^2+\beta' t+\gamma')\Big),\quad 0\leq t\leq T.
\end{align}
When are these signals orthogonal? I understand that if $\alpha=\alpha'$ and $\beta-\beta'=2n/T$ for any integer $n$ these two signals are orthogonal. Is there any other case for orthogonality? Another question is whether there is any closed form for the distance between these two signals, i.e.,
$$
d(x,y)=\int_0^T |x(t)-y(t)|^2 \, dt.
$$
I know these are simple questions, but I could not find any resources for comparison to reassure me that I am on the correct path.

Comment: this is indeed the only orthogonality condition; the expression for the distance integral is too lengthy for a comment, see below.

Answer (score 8):

just for the record, the distance function has a complicated expression in terms of the imaginary error function erfi:

<sub>$$d(x,y)=2T+\operatorname{Re}\,\left\{(\alpha+\alpha')^{-1/2}(-1)^{3/4} \left[\text{erfi}\left(\frac{(-1)^{1/4} \sqrt{\pi } (2 T (\alpha+\alpha')+\beta+\beta')}{2 \sqrt{\alpha+\alpha'}}\right)-\text{erfi}\left(\frac{(-1)^{1/4} \sqrt{\pi } (\beta+\beta')}{2 \sqrt{\alpha+\alpha'}}\right)\right]\right.$$
$$\left.\qquad\times \exp \left(\frac{i \pi  \left(4 (\alpha+\alpha') (\gamma+\gamma')-(\beta+\beta')^2\right)}{4 (\alpha+\alpha')}\right)\right\}.$$</sub>